# Parsing xml DOM child nodes with java

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I have following structure of xml

```
<entities>
        <entity>
            <type>FieldTerminology</type>
            <relevance>0.732316</relevance>
            <sentiment>
                <type>negative</type>
                <score>-0.351864</score>
            </sentiment>
            <count>2</count>
            <text>financial crisis</text>
        </entity>
        <entity>
            <type>Company</type>
            <relevance>0.496572</relevance>
            <sentiment>
                <type>neutral</type>
            </sentiment>
            <count>1</count>
            <text>Goldman Sachs</text>
            <disambiguated>
                <name>Goldman Sachs</name>
                <subType>CompanyShareholder</subType>
                <website>http://www.gs.com/</website>
                <dbpedia>http://dbpedia.org/resource/Goldman_Sachs</dbpedia>
                <freebase>http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/m.01xdn1</freebase>
                <yago>http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/Goldman_Sachs</yago>
                <crunchbase>http://www.crunchbase.com/company/goldman-sachs</crunchbase>
            </disambiguated>
        </entity>
```

I am parsing all, only I cant access to child sentiment
with this how can i access also "sentiment" in each entity node?

```
 NodeList feeds = docs.getElementsByTagName("entities");
            for (int i = 0; i < feeds.getLength(); i++) {
                Node mainNode = feeds.item(i);
                if (mainNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element firstElement = (Element) mainNode;
                    System.out.println("First element " + firstElement.getTagName());
                    NodeList forumidNameList = firstElement.getElementsByTagName("entity");

                    for (int j = 0; j < forumidNameList.getLength(); ++j) {
                        Element value = (Element) forumidNameList.item(j);

                        NodeList conditionList = value.getElementsByTagName("relevance");
                        for (int k = 0; k < conditionList.getLength(); ++k) {
                            Element condition = (Element) conditionList.item(k);
                            String conditionText = condition.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                            System.out.println("relevance " + conditionText);
                        }
                        NodeList conditionList1 = value.getElementsByTagName("type");
                        for (int k = 0; k < conditionList1.getLength(); ++k) {
                            Element condition = (Element) conditionList1.item(k);
                            String conditionText = condition.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                            System.out.println("type " + conditionText);
                        }
                        NodeList conditionList2 = value.getElementsByTagName("count");
                        for (int k = 0; k < conditionList2.getLength(); ++k) {
                            Element condition = (Element) conditionList2.item(k);
                            String conditionText = condition.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                            System.out.println("count " + conditionText);
                        }
                        NodeList conditionList3 = value.getElementsByTagName("text");
                        for (int k = 0; k < conditionList3.getLength(); ++k) {
                            Element condition = (Element) conditionList3.item(k);
                            String conditionText = condition.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                            System.out.println("text " + conditionText);
                        }
```

I need parse list of entities and also subnodes.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are asking here.  Are you only interested in the information in the `sentiment` nodes?

Comment: not only, also all subnodes

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not clear on what you want.  When I run your code, it looks like the output already shows the content of sentiment nodes.  Can you please edit your question to show an example of what you would like the output to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have attempted to get you question solved,I made the following changes
1. Added the missing node parsing for `<sentiment>`
2. Improvised your parsing logic for `<type>` node as it would appear twice because of same name in the dom structure.

Note: I would still recommend to use JAXB, XPath for efficient xml parsing. Hope that  helps
Here the code.

```
    NodeList feeds = doc.getElementsByTagName("entities");
    for (int i = 0; i < feeds.getLength(); i++) {
        Node mainNode = feeds.item(i);
        if (mainNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element firstElement = (Element) mainNode;
            System.out.println("First element "
                    + firstElement.getTagName());
            NodeList forumidNameList = firstElement
                    .getElementsByTagName("entity");

            for (int j = 0; j < forumidNameList.getLength(); ++j) {
                Element value = (Element) forumidNameList.item(j);

                NodeList conditionList = value
                        .getElementsByTagName("type");
                for (int k = 0; k < conditionList.getLength(); ++k) {
                    Element condition = (Element) conditionList.item(k);
                    if (condition.getParentNode().getNodeName()
                            .equals("entity")) {
                        String conditionText = condition
                                .getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                        System.out.println("type " + conditionText);

                    }
                }
                NodeList conditionList1 = value
                        .getElementsByTagName("relevance");
                for (int k = 0; k < conditionList1.getLength(); ++k) {
                    Element condition = (Element) conditionList1
                            .item(k);
                    String conditionText = condition.getFirstChild()
                            .getNodeValue();
                    System.out.println("relevance " + conditionText);
                }
                NodeList conditionList2 = value
                        .getElementsByTagName("sentiment");
                for (int k = 0; k < conditionList2.getLength(); ++k) {
                    Element condition = (Element) conditionList2
                            .item(k);
                    for (int l = 0; l < condition.getChildNodes()
                            .getLength(); ++l) {
                        Element condition2 = (Element) condition
                                .getChildNodes().item(l);
                        String conditionText = condition2
                                .getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                        System.out
                                .println("sentiment " + conditionText);
                    }
                }
                NodeList conditionList3 = value
                        .getElementsByTagName("count");
                for (int k = 0; k < conditionList3.getLength(); ++k) {
                    Element condition = (Element) conditionList3
                            .item(k);
                    String conditionText = condition.getFirstChild()
                            .getNodeValue();
                    System.out.println("count " + conditionText);
                }
                NodeList conditionList4 = value
                        .getElementsByTagName("text");
                for (int k = 0; k < conditionList4.getLength(); ++k) {
                    Element condition = (Element) conditionList4
                            .item(k);
                    String conditionText = condition.getFirstChild()
                            .getNodeValue();
                    System.out.println("text " + conditionText);
                }
            }
        }
    }
output
----------------
First element entities
type FieldTerminology
relevance 0.732316
sentiment negative
sentiment -0.351864
count 2
text financial crisis
type Company
relevance 0.496572
sentiment neutral
count 1
text Goldman Sachs
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a different parser? I've found that DOM struggled to handle more complex XML structures. I'd recommend trying JDOM which I found was much better at handling access issues such as yours.